# change font in UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView`, in which I have one `UILabel`. I would like to change the `UILabel.Font` to a custom `UIFont` when the `UIView` is tapped (This enlarges the tappable area instead of using a `UIButton`).

To add the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, I use the following code:

```
var gestureRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer ((item) => {
    (item.View.Subviews[0] as UILabel).Font = Constants_iOS.FONT_OS_SMALL_LABEL_SEMIBOLD;
});
view.AddGestureRecognizer (gestureRecognizer);
```

The font change gets executed, and stepping through the code shows the font changing. But it does not update in the UI, and all subsequent executions of the function also start with the `Font` being the old one.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that a UITableview header gets redrawn each time it gets tapped. So your font change will not persist.

Answer (score 0):

Add tap `selector` method.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
tap.delegate = self
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func handleTap(sender:UIGestureRecognizer){
   //change your font here
}
```

Comment: have u added the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Comment: Yes, and it still does not work. But I think I got the problem, I'm doing this inside a UITableView's header view, which apparently gets rebuilt every time it is tapped. So I was performing the font change and then rebuilding the headerview...